# Multivariate polynomial division in a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to do a polynomial division in the quotient ring $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3),$ where $(X^2-Y^3)$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $X^2-Y^3.$ Let's take the example $$g = 2x^4y - 3x^2y^3 + x^3 -3y^2 + x + 2y +2 + (X^2-Y^3), \,g\in \mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3).$$ If we set $g = p + (X^2-Y^3)$, then long polynomial division of $p$ by $x^2- y^3$ leads to $$p = (2x^2y + 2y^4 - 3y^3 + x)(x^2-y^3) + 2y^7-3y^6 -3y^2 +xy^3+x+2y+2.$$

Since the degree of the variable $y$ in the remainder is $\geq 3,$ I used the property in the quotient ring $X^2 = Y^3.$ I get for the remainder : $2x^4y - 3x^4 -3y^2 + x^3 +x +2y +2.$ If I now continue with the division I obtain terms that appeared right at the beginning and this continues (maybe endlessly).

Can somebody point out where I am doing the mistake and eventually propose a solution of the division in the quotient ring based on the example given above. Many thanks.

Comment: This ring doesn’t have unique factorization, so it can’t have a division algorithm.

Comment: You certainly can't divide by $x^{2}-y^{3}$; that's $0$ in this ring!

Comment: Thanks. Why it doesn't have unique factorization?

Comment: By means of the canonical homomorphism one assigns to each polynomial in R[X, Y] an element of the quotient ring by the division.

Comment: If you want a normal form for elements in the quotient ring, you can replace $y^3$ by $x^2$, and stop as soon as all powers of $y$ are $\le 2$.  Alternatively, you can replace all $x^2$ by $y^3$ and stop as soon as all powers of $x$ are $\le 1$. These will give two different normal forms.

Comment: Thanks. Since $X^2-Y^3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ and thus the quotient ring is integral, how can one check if the quotient ring is unique factorization domain ?